# Is the set of integers so that $n!+1$ divides $(2012n)!$ finite or infinite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I am having trouble with this problem. We have to determine whether the set of integers such that $n!+1$ divides $(2012n)!$ is finite or infinite. Basically we have to determine if the prime factors of $n!+1$ are small enough for a finite or infinite number of integers, but I have not been able to make much progress.

Comment: This is an interesting question,  Erdos proved that : n!+1 is divisible by a prime greater than $2n$

Comment: @Elaqqad Oh, I didn't know that. That's awesome. Perhaps he also proved it for coefficients larger than $2$ but only for large enough values of $n$? That would solve the problem.

Comment: @Elaqqad $4!+1=25$ which is divided only by the prime $5<2\cdot 4=8$.

Comment: Oh snap, perhaps it's for large enough $n$?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-27.pdf

Comment: It doesn't look very useful.

Comment: You'll find this [helpful](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2012/IMC2012-day2-solutions.pdf)

Comment: How did you know it came from that test?

Comment: I've solved this problem once and I remembered where it came from and the number 2012 in front of n suggests the year

Comment: @OfirSchnabel I mean for infinitely many integers $n$, because the question is asking wither $n!+1$ is divisible by a prime greater than 2012n for an infinite number of integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that for $n$ large $(2012n)!$ contains way too many factors that are factors of $n!$, and that the remaining stuff is smaller than $n!+1$.

Specifically $n!+1$ must divide $\dfrac{(2012n)!}{n!^{2012}}$ which can be bounded sufficiently well by using the bound $m! < m^m$ on the numerator and $m!> (m/e)^m$.

we get $\dfrac{(2012n)!}{n!^{2012}} < e^{2012n}$.

And for $n$ large we have $n!+1 > e^{2012n}$, so there can be at most a finite number of values of $n$ where the divisibility holds.